# Vue.js props for multiple childs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parent-child, vuex

I have parent component that is fetch data from Back End and multiple childs component that only draw diargams inside parent and need Back End data. Can't find the answer - how to give props for several child component from parent? Is there any example? Probles is ONLY first component receives fresh data, others receives only data from parent `data() return` but not refreshed from Back End.

This is parent:

```
<template>
```

```
<panel-group
  :ticketsProp="tickets"
  :airportsProp="airports"
  :aircraftsProp="aircrafts"
  :pilotsProp="pilots"></panel-group>

<el-row :gutter="32">
  <el-col :xs="24" :sm="24" :lg="8">
    <div class="chart-wrapper">
      <bar-chart :msg="message"></bar-chart>
    </div>
  </el-col>
  <el-col :xs="24" :sm="24" :lg="8">
    <div class="chart-wrapper">
      <pie-chart :disregardProp="disregard"></pie-chart>
    </div>
  </el-col>
  <el-col :xs="24" :sm="24" :lg="8">
    <div class="chart-wrapper">
      <persent-of-assessed :assessedProp="assessed"></persent-of-assessed>
    </div>
  </el-col>
</el-row>
```

```
data() {
    return {
      dataLoading: true,
      dataFromDB: null,
      message: 'This is test',
      tickets: 0,
      aircrafts: 0,
      pilots: 0,
      airports: 0,
      assessed: 0,
      disregard: 0
    }
  }

    created() {
    this.getData()
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      this.dataLoading = true
      getDashboardStat().then(response => {
        this.dataFromDB = response.data
        this.listLoading = false
      }).then(() => {
        this.tickets = this.dataFromDB.ticketsAmount
        this.airports = this.dataFromDB.airportsAmount
        this.aircrafts = this.dataFromDB.aircraftAmount
        this.pilots = this.dataFromDB.pilotsAmount
        this.disregard = this.dataFromDB.sumOfDisregard
        this.assessed = this.dataFromDB.percentOfAssessed
```

Example of child I think not needed, because they get data, problem that sended data id wrong.

Comment: The code you posted seems missing some parts. Can you please double check?

Comment: Correction: If your using Vuex, don't use props...

Comment: Could you please post a code snippet?

Comment: Thank you all! My mistake that I didn't use global bus or Vuex, and problem is that the parent component life cycle is independent from childs components life cycles.

Answer (score 1):

as i understand you, the solution for you might be [dynamic component.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)

if youm add an array of components names to your `data`, (after you imported all of them and registered them in the `components` property) such as

```
data() {
    return {
      componentsArr:['panelGroup',
                     'secondComponent',
                     'thirdComponent'],
      dataLoading: true,
      dataFromDB: null,
      message: 'This is test',
      tickets: 0,
      aircrafts: 0,
      pilots: 0,
      airports: 0,
      assessed: 0,
      disregard: 0,

    }
  },
components:{
   exampleComponent,
   panelGroup,
   secondComponent,
   thirdComponent
}
```

then in your template you loop over that array using [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html), and [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)
(to make sure it wont get rendered before you fetch the data you need):

```
<component v-if=" ! dataLoading" v-for="comp in componentsArr" :is="comp"
  :ticketsProp="tickets"
  :airportsProp="airports"
  :aircraftsProp="aircrafts"
  :pilotsProp="pilots"></component>
```

Comment: Thanks fr trying help but this is not working. First of all Vues asks for :key, I give him :key="comp" and childs components still dont have data and redndering inside themselves recursevely.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this promblem need to use global bus or Vuex, because life cycle of childrens are independent from parent life cycle. I made by global bus and it's works, by example of Andrejs Abrickis:

```
// event-bus.js
import Vue from 'vue';
const EventBus = new Vue();
export default EventBus;

// component-a.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import EventBus from './event-bus';
Vue.component('component-a', {
  ...
  methods: {
    emitMethod () {
       EventBus.$emit('EVENT_NAME', payLoad);
    }
  }
});

// component-b.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import EventBus from './event-bus';
Vue.component(‘component-b’, {
  ...
  mounted () {
    EventBus.$on(‘EVENT_NAME’, function (payLoad) {
      ...
    });
  }
});
```